# Setting a custom size of thumbnails images pulled from JQUERY/FLICKR API

Tags: jquery, image, json, feed, flickr

I am adding a gallery to a website and I want to pull the images from a flickr account.

I have it working but I would like to set a custom size to the thumbnails not just the small , meduim and large, css works for the frame but the image inside gets distorted so can the size be set in jquery ??

the code im using (my api and id are 00000 for this post only) to pull the flickr feed is:

```
$(function() {
var apiKey = '000000000000000000000000000000';
var userId = '000000000';
var tag = 'gsow,cycle,event';
var perPage = '20';
var showOnPage = '8';

$.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?format=json&method='+
    'flickr.photos.search&api_key=' + apiKey + '&user_id=' + userId + 
    '&tags=' + tag + '&per_page=' + perPage + '&jsoncallback=?', 
function(data){
    var classShown = 'class="lightbox"';
    var classHidden = 'class="lightbox hidden"';

    $.each(data.photos.photo, function(i, rPhoto){
        var basePhotoURL = 'http://farm' + rPhoto.farm + '.static.flickr.com/'
            + rPhoto.server + '/' + rPhoto.id + '_' + rPhoto.secret;

        var thumbPhotoURL = basePhotoURL + '_s.jpg';
        var mediumPhotoURL = basePhotoURL + '.jpg';

        var photoStringStart = '<a ';
        var photoStringEnd = 'title="' + rPhoto.title + '" href="'+ 
            mediumPhotoURL +'"><img src="' + thumbPhotoURL + '" alt="' + 
            rPhoto.title + '"/></a>;'
        var photoString = (i < showOnPage) ? 
            photoStringStart + classShown + photoStringEnd : 
            photoStringStart + classHidden + photoStringEnd;

        $(photoString).appendTo("#flickr");
    });
    $("a.lightbox").lightBox();
});
```

});

anyone ever have this issue?

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't *overflow: hidden* do the trick?

As in:

```
img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can only retrieve a certain [list of fixed sizes for Flickr thumbnail photos](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html), for example s (small square 75x75), q (large square 150x150), t (thumbnail, 100 on longest side), etc. For a dynamic size you would probably need some kind of cropping tool like [Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html).

Answer (score 0):

I normally pull the most appropriate size (_s or _m) and the use css cropping. Wrap the image in a div width 100%. With overflow:hidden you can crop the image.